# Fit image+text vertically inside a fancyBox

Tags: html, css, fancybox-2

I'm trying to display a vertical, hi-res image with text above and below inside a small [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).

I cannot know beforehand how big the fancyBox will be: the fancyBox will be automatically sized to accommodate the client viewport.

The end result should be the image being proportionally re-sized to fit inside the available area, leaving enough space above and below for the text. In other words: I need the whole thing (text+image) "above the fold":

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SkiBEeM.png]

The problem is: I'm stuck and **width is ok, height doesn't** and so I've a vertical scrollbar:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/D133vNm.png]

**My example is here**: http://jsfiddle.net/sexyzane/wv05f8ez/4/ but the relevant part of the code is the CSS:

```
#viewbox > img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

I think I got the basics almost right (if I remove the `max-width` rule, I get an horizontal scroll bar too, as expected) but, still, the `max-height` seems to be ignored (in my jsfiddle is set to 5%, but setting it to 50% or 500% seems to be irrelevant).

Extra kudos for a Javascript-less solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should give bootstrap a try.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples

Comment: I did, but I still cannot fix this situation. Could you please provide a jsfiddle with a Bootstrap-based solution to the question? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add css for parent of you image

```
div#viewbox {
    display: block;
    height: 96%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then add object-fit: cover; property to image so that image resolution always will be maintain

```
#viewbox > img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height:35%;
  max-width: 100%;
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

here is the link that I have worked on http://jsfiddle.net/wv05f8ez/5/ I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh,  you took care of the max-height being ignored, but still, that fixed 35% is forcing the solution to work at that specific viewport: if you try with a bigger viewport, the image is too small ( http://i.imgur.com/L8GztpS.png , http://jsfiddle.net/sexyzane/wv05f8ez/6/ ). As i stated, *I cannot know beforehand how big the fancyBox will be: the fancyBox will be automatically sized to accommodate the client viewport.*

Comment: OK height and width issue you want to fix according to the viewport then you need to write media queries or else you need to apply width and height via Javascript or jquery by calculating viewport height and width